# WebSockets working on localhost, but do not work on remote Ubuntu host

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, websocket

I have two applications - browser based client and NodeJS based server that are both communicating using WebSockets (I'm using ColyseusJS library). Problem is, that everything works fine while I'm testing them on localhost but when I deploy the application to my Ubuntu VPS server it stops working.

The message I receive in the browser while trying to connect is:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://X.X.X.X:8001/?colyseusid=' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

So it reaches the server (because when server is disabled the message is "Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED") but it looks like it fails on Upgrade connection operation.

What is strange is that I managed to make it work yesterday (don't know how exactly), but had so much mess on my VPS that I decided to revert machine to it's starting state. After that it stopped working (code is unchanged). Maybe there are some additional dependencies that I need to install in order to make it work on my Ubuntu Server?

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to port forward the port to the ip address of the said VPS in your router config? And also check out the firewalls.

Comment: Yes, I found out that it is environmental issue with my network. Your comment gave me idea to check website from my mobile phone using mobile internet and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Hi i am using mobile data and i made static ip on wifi not. but still i am getting same problem. can you please help me out.